# Disassembler for Renesas RX62 micro

Tags: disassemblers

Does anybody know a free disassembler tool for decoding a Renesas RX62 micrcocontroller binary file? There had been www.onlinedisassembler.com, but this site is down and the new beta.onlinedisassembler.com does not integrate the RX type for disassembling. It would be fine too if it would be an offline tool, for sure...

Answer (score 1):

Renesas provides a [GNU toolchain for the RX series](https://gcc-renesas.com/rx-download-toolchains/) which likely includes `objdump` tool which should be able to disassemble code for RX.